# React is not rendering as state value

Tags: reactjs, state, rendering

I have  a React component, where i want to do conditional rendering.

## Code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style/style.css";
class Menu  extends React.Component{
    state = {
        menuState:10
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.menuState)
        if(this.state.menuState === 1 || this.state.menuState === 2)
            return <div className="menu">
                <h1>Menu </h1>
            </div>

        return <div className="menu-bar">
            <h1>Not menu</h1>
        </div>
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

As you can see in this code, if `menuState` is 1 or 2 then i want to return **Menu** otherwise **Not menu**. For convenience, i initialize `menuState` with 10. It  returns nothing, nither `menu` or `not menu`.

#### When i set `menuState` with 1 or 2 then it returns Menu.

```js
state = {
        menuState:1
    }
```

Comment: What happens with this code? I see it still oke to render `"Not menu"` with menuState=10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seem to be fine. You can check css for "menu-bar"

Comment: CSS file is empty.

Comment: I just started coding, so i first checked weather it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style/style.css";

class Menu  extends React.Component{
    state = {
        menuState:10
    }
render(){
    console.log(this.state.menuState)
    return(
        <div>
           {(this.state.menuState === 1 || this.state.menuState === 2) ? <h1>Menu </h1> : <h1>Not menu</h1>}
        </div>
        
      )
    }
  }
 export default Menu;
```

Second solution:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style/style.css";

class Menu  extends React.Component{
  state = {
    menuState:1
  }

_conditional(){
    if(this.state.menuState === 1 || this.state.menuState === 2)
        return <div className="menu">
            <h1>Menu </h1>
        </div>

    return <div className="menu-bar">
        <h1>Not menu</h1>
    </div>
}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.menuState)
    return(
        <div>
            {this._conditional()}
        </div>
        
    )
   }
 }
export default Menu;
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic ?

Comment: React docs tells us about conditional rendering. We can apply if,else,switch etc in render() method

Comment: Yes you can apply them anywhere except inside the JSX, use ternary expression or call a function like I did. The  [Documentation](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) explains this better with examples.

Comment: If you use them inside JSX then when JSX is transformed into JavaScript it becomes invalid JavaScript code